# Can't login/associate OpenID

Tags: bug, status-completed, area-51

I have an Area51 account (not OpenID) which I setup to get involved in the proposed Ubuntu site. I can't now logon to the Ubuntu site because it wants OpenID and not the account I signed up to Area51 with.

Answer (score 1):

We're working on a solution to this where you'll get an email with a special token to let you log in, but for now you can work around this by doing the following:

1. Register an OpenID on Area 51
2. Use that same OpenID to log into the beta site